# Sitecore XSL: Select item by path or id, get children, get Droplink item of child

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, sitecore

I have almost no experience with XSL and I need some help. I have a component that was rendered in an ASCX file but needs to be moved to be within an XSL file, and I'm not sure of the Syntax.

I have a Sitecore item, `/sitecore/content/Home/Social Media Link Group`; I need all the children of this item, `/sitecore/content/Home/Social Media Link Group/[Social Media Item]`. This item has two fields: `Social Media Source Name`, a Droplink field; and `Social Media Link`, a Link (I know this is overly complicated, I did not create this).

The droplink item has two fields: `Social Media Source Name` and `Social Media Source Css Class`

So in XSL, what I need to do it get all the children of a specific root item; for each item, get the Link field and the Droplink item, and get the two fields from the Droplink item

So, I'm not sure how to render this in XSL. Here's where I got started, but it's throwing an error, and I'm not sure how to debug XSL either. This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="item" select="sc:item(sc:fld('__display name'), $socialShareLinks)" />
<xsl:for-each select="sc:CHILDREN??">
  <xsl:variable name="socialItem" select="sc:item(.,.)"/>
  <xsl:varible name="linkedItem" select="sc:field('Social Media Link Source', $socialItem)"/>
  <xsl:varible name="itemClass" select="sc:field('Social Media Source Css Class', $linkedItem"/>
  <li class="$itemClass">
    <sc:link field="Social Media Link"></sc:link>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to write this correctly? 1) I don't know how to get the sc:children. 2) Visual Studio is telling me that I cannot have an xsl:variable inside an xsl:for-each, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do instead. 3) Any other things I've gotten wrong.

EDIT: I've updated my code to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$socialShareRoot/item">
  <li class="float-left">

    <xsl:variable name="itemUrl" select="sc:fld('Social Media Link', ., 'Url')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="LinkedItemId" select="sc:fld('Social Media Link Source', ., 'id')" />
    <xsl:variable name="SocialShareItem" select="sc:item($LinkedItemId, . )" />

    <xsl:variable name="itemClass" select="sc:fld('Social Media Source Css Class', $SocialShareItem)"/>               
    <xsl:variable name="itemName" select="sc:fld('Social Media Source Name', $SocialShareItem)"/>

    <a target="_blank">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="$itemClass"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$itemUrl"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:value-of select="$LinkedItemId"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm getting an empty  for every existing item in Sitecore, but not getting any values for class, name, or url

Comment: XSLT renderings are deprecated. You should really think about using MVC renderings instead. If you can't, try examples from this doc: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_xsl_reference_sc62-64-a4.pdf